# jQuery object is undefined after ready

Tags: jquery, undefined

I have a weird problem with jQuery, the "$" becomes undefined after executing all the code under the ready event.

Any experience in this error? or any idea what is causing this?

Comment: can you show the code...

Comment: probably it's the conflict between your js libraries inside your webpage causes this error. I remember JQuery has a function for this, can't remember though.

Answer (score 1):

Put jQuery code inside this snipet, because $ might be defined for something else.

```
(function($) {

    // $ Works! You can test it with next line if you like
    // console.log($);

})( jQuery );
```

Comment: if $ is already defined for something else, I think it should return "Object" if I write it in the console right?
because in this case its undefined

Comment: That is what i get when i try to put jQuery on Wordpress $ get Undefined. @thedjaney

Comment: Yeah, I know this solution... but it seems to be a different issue.. Thanks anyway @Cody

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
    (function ($) {
           $(document);
           // your code
    }(jQuery));
</script>
```